# What can cause an anchor tag does not fill a li tag?

Tags: css

Basically, I have an `ul` with 3 `li`'s, all floated to the left, the first and the last with `width: 20%` and the second `li` with `width: 60%`.

I have an anchor tag inside the second `li` element, with some text, and `display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center;`.

The thing is that the text is not centered because the anchor tag doesn't fill the li tag.

What can cause that ?

EDIT:

I had `float: left;` in the anchor tag. Stupid mistake, thank you all.

Comment: throw an example up on jsfiddle

Comment: ? li[0] = 20% + li[1] = 80% + li[2] = 20% == 120% or am i Misreading your question. This is why code example is always better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried your case out in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tza5r/) have it working as you intended.

I removed from the anchor tag:

```
width: 100%;
```

Check it out and compare, if you don't find anything you messed up, maybe there is something else in your code that prevents that from working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using the small amount of code you provided that does not exhibit your problem.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: salmon;
}

.link {
    width: 80%;
    background: lightblue;
}

.link a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

There is something in your code you didn't tell us about that is causing your problem. Study this simple example to find out what it is.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9AgG/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: block` from the `<a>` when using `width: 100%`.